# Am I understanding the jQuery delegate function correctly?

Tags: jquery, dom, event-handling, jquery-delegate

I know that a div will appear at some point in my page's future DOM, and I know the id of it (it's generated by SharePoint javascript) - is it possible for me to use [jQuery delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to attach an event handler to this div prior to it existing in the DOM?

Also, how does this compare to .live() for this particular scenario?

Comment: which version of JQuery are you using? from that link you posted, `'As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.'` I'd recommend you look at `.on()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes**

Long answer: As of jQuery 1.7+ [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is prefered before the two you have mentioned, they are deprecated. This is an example on [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
    $('#parent').on("click", "span.children", function() {
        if ( confirm("Are you sure?") ) {
            console.log(this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: So, with the code you've provided - I'm assuming I can swap span.children for another jQuery selector? (i.e. explicitly naming the id of the div that may appear at some point in the future)?

Comment: @DeeMac Oh-so-correct! You need to change the parent selector also though.

Comment: @DeeMac Also, if your going to add more children than one: Use a class instead of an id. For instance in this example, all spans with the class .children will be binded to this click event.

Comment: $(document).on("click", "#ms-cui-menu.children", function() { alert('test'); }) - does this look right @sQVe? i.e - when any children of the li ms-cui-menu are clicked, the alert will be shown? It doesn't appear to be working, can't work out why.

Comment: @DeeMac `$("#ms-cui-menu").on("click", ".children", function() { alert('test'); })` is probably correct, try it.

Comment: #ms-cui-menu isn't always there from the start either though, put I don't think attaching a click event handler to the list will cut it because it's its child elements that will be clicked.

Comment: @DeeMac Well, preferably you want a #parent closer to the child elements than document is, otherwise you loose preformance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do this, but you could use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method instead, and don't use `.live`, it is deprecated.

```
$(elements).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(elements).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if `elements` doesn't exist, would it? Correct me if I'm wrong please

Comment: @davids Yes, so the events should be delegated at the parents element which exist. The future elements should be the `selector`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.on()`. And you should never use `.live()`.

For a performance test between the three see: http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-delegate-vs-on

Besides the fact that `.live()` is deprecated it is also very slow compared to the other two.

Basically what you are doing with `.on()` or `.delegate()` is add eventhandlers to elements within a container whether the elements already exist or if it is added to the DOM dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can, but both methods have been superseded in favour of [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) on recent versions of jQuery.

Also, [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) always attaches the event handler to the (top of the) document, whilst [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) allows you to choose where to attach the events, thus it can be more efficient if you know before hand where the element is going to be.